# Load data from google sheet on start up

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried to retrieve a list of agents who are stored in a google sheet. The problem that I am facing right now is that I can get the list of agents in the script file. However, when I try to pass it to an html file, I keep getting null for the list. I absolutely has no idea how that can be.

Can someone give me an idea where I should look for?

My script:

```
var DB_URL = "";
var AGENT_DB = "";

var CREATED_ON_IDX = 0;
var NAME_IDX = 1;
var EMAIL_IDX = 2;


function agentService_getAgents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(DB_URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(AGENT_DB);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var agents = [];
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
    var row = values[i];
    var name = row[NAME_IDX];
    var email = row[EMAIL_IDX];
    var createdOn = row[CREATED_ON_IDX];
    var agent = new Agent(name, email, createdOn);

    agents[i-1] = agent;
  } 
  Logger.log(agents);
  return agents;
}
```

Ajax call in Html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function onSuccess(agents) {
        var $table = $("table");
        console.log(agents);

      }

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .agentService_getAgents();
    </script>
```

So Logger.log(agents) gives me a list of agent; but console.log(agents) gives me null.

Comment: You're logging the agents `Logger.log(agents);`, can you see them in script logs ?

Comment: @dkn Can you add the information of your situation? I think that adding the information will help users think of about your issue. 1. How do you run the HTML and the script? This is about ``start up`` in your title. 2. Can you provide the detail information about ``var agent = new Agent(name, email, createdOn)``? This is also commented by ra89fi.

Comment: What is createdOn? If it is a Date, you can not pass date to client.  See parameters and return values at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: @ra89fi Yes, I can see it in my log. Agent is just an object to hold the information that I parse from the sheet

Comment: @TheWizEd thank you for your hint. It is because of the date that I cannot pass to the client the agents.

Comment: What you could do is JSON.stringify each object and store in the array, then JSON.parse on the client side.